# Powershell - IE | Bypass - This site is not secure

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

My PS1 file is just launching a site in IE. I am unable to navigate to the URL due to This site is not secure prompt. I need to bypass this prompt and my workaround is not working. I think I may be improperly selecting more information with sslbypass. Is there a different way to bypass?

```
"Starting Internet Explorer in Background"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$uri = 'https://soti10app1/MobiControl/WebConsole/'
$ie.navigate("$uri")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100};
if ($ie.document.url -Match "invalidcert")
        {
        "Bypassing SSL Certificate Error Page";
        #$sslbypass=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | ?{$_.href -match "javascript:expandCollapse('infoBlockID', true);"}
        #$sslbypass.click();
        $sslbypass=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | where-object {$_.id -eq "overridelink"};
        $sslbypass.click();
        "sleep for 5 seconds while final page loads";
        start-sleep -s 5;
        };
if ($ie.Document.domain -Match "soti10app1", "soti10app2", "soti10app3")
        {
        "Successfully Bypassed SSL Error";
        }
        else
        {
        "Bypass failed";
        }
get-process iexplore | stop-process
```

The page that loads when running script.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newErrorPageTemplate.css">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>This site isn&rsquo;t secure</title>

        <script src="invalidcert.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script src="errorPageStrings.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script src="httpErrorPagesScripts.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="BodyLoad(); initMoreInfo('infoBlockID');">
        <div id="contentContainer" class="mainContent">
            <div id="invalidcert_mainTitle" class="title" style="color: #a90000;">This site is not secure</div>
            <div id="invalidcert_subError" class="BodyTextBlockStyle">
                This might mean that someone&rsquo;s trying to fool you or steal any info you send to the server. You should close this site immediately.<br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="BaseTextBlockStyle"><a href="javascript:close();"><img class="shieldImage" alt="Recommended icon" src="shieldcheck.ico" width="20px" height="20px"><id id="invalidcert_closeTab">Close this tab</id></a><br></div>

            <div id="moreInformationAlign" align="left" aria-labelledby="moreInformation">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" aria-labelledby="infoBlockIDImage">
                            <a href="#" onclick="javascript:expandCollapse('infoBlockID', true); return false;"><img src="down.png" id="infoBlockIDImage" border="0" class="actionIcon" alt="More information"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <span id="moreInfoContainer"></span>
                            <noscript><id id="moreInformation">More information</id></noscript>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div id="infoBlockID" class="infoBlock" style="display: none">
                    <br/>
                    <b><span id="certReason" style="margin-left:20px"></span></b>
                    <p id="ErrorCode" style="margin-left:20px"></p>
                    <p class="BaseTextBlockStyle" id="override" style="margin-left:20px"><a href="#" id="overridelink"><img class="shieldImage" alt="Not recommended icon" src="shieldcritical.ico" width="20px" height="20px">Go on to the webpage (not recommended)</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I bypass this page and continue to my $uri?

Comment: Do you mean the $uri is the target page, when access that page, it will redirect to the secure page? If that is the case, can you tell us why it will redirect to the secure page, is there any limit or authentication? From the secure page code, after click the "Close this tab" button it will close current tab, so I think we need to check why it will redirect the secure page and prevent it.

Comment: Its IE on a corporate network. Secure site prompts for a lot of different things and disabling the IE settings for security requires reboot which our GP will then reapply the default browser settings. I cannot make any changes to my browser or my network and am attempting to try to hit my target URI and if I do hit this site is not secure then target more information and the continue override button.

Comment: I figured there may be another way to bypass this when making a request to a target site that is not secure. I believe the applications are setup over 3 servers with load balancing and thats why I check for a domain match for 3 different domains. Seems anything with load balancing will prompt this site is not secure and require user to hit more info and continue to reach target site.

Comment: Have you ever found the solution and solved this problem?

Comment: I have not solved this yet unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: I'm working on this in an intranet network with self-signed certificates. I strongly wouldn't suggest anyone actually utilizing this code elsewhere.**

I ran into this same problem, and it's like the page document isn't fully loading. I've bypassed it with the below code.

```
$IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$IE.visible=$true
$IE.FullScreen=$false
$IE.ToolBar = $false
$IE.StatusBar = $false
$IE.MenuBar = $false
$IE.AddressBar = $true
$IE.Resizable = $true
$IE.navigate2("https://URL.com")
$i=0
While ( $IE.busy -eq $true ) { 
   Start-Sleep -s 1
   $i = $i + 1
   if ( $i -ge 20 ) { break }
}
$overrideLink = $IE.document.links | where-object {$_.id -eq "overridelink" }
$overrideLink.click()
```

However, it looks like the fun continues when you're past this page. I still need to login and looks like I'll need to iterate through "$IE.document.forms" to perform that instead of utilizing $IE.document.getElementById("username") . If you also need to perform a login, I was successful with adding the following code.

```
#Need to wait for webpage to load after bypassing
$i=0
While ( $IE.busy -eq $true ) { 
   Start-Sleep -s 1
   $i = $i + 1
   if ( $i -ge 20 ) { break }
}

$loginForm = $IE.document.forms[0]

$usernameForm = $loginForm.children | Where-Object { $_.innerHTML -match "j_username" } #This contains the HTML for the form, so it will always contain the id
$usernameField = $usernameForm.children | Where-Object {$_.id -eq "j_username" }
$usernameField.value = "USERNAME"

$passwordForm = $loginForm.children | Where-Object { $_.innerHTML -match "j_password" } #This contains the HTML for the form, so it will always contain the id
$passwordField = $passwordForm.children | Where-Object {$_.id -eq "j_password" }
$passwordField.value = "PASSWORD"

$loginForm.submit()
```